# Low beam headlights don't work. High work. Can't find the problem

Tags: ford, headlight, focus, relay

Car: 2012 Ford Focus

The fuse location under the passenger compartment works - I tested. I don't know if it's the headlight relay, but my car manual does not show a location. Unless it's listed under a different name - so I don't know where to look. I know there are recalls on this vehicle year, but the Ford site says my vehicle is not.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance and Repair!  Have you tried replacing the bulbs?  Often (most?) times, low beams will go out first, as that's what people use the most.  They're often different bulbs too.

Comment: They were working and stopped? Do you have automatic lights sensor?